# is there any possibility of skipping import error build failing

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi i have situation where i don't want to bundle some `import` of some component when it is not found in `node_modules/`

My Architecture is something like this

[image]

Based on above architecture i will export/emit  `component Object`  from **Plugin App** side , actual import will happen  in **MAIN APP** side

I have tried to find solution to with linting https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/  but did not find any

**Expectation:** import inside **Plugin App** `import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'` must be treated as proxy and actual `import` will going to happen in **MAIN APP**

**Note:** i'm using `vue2.x` version

Comment: This looks like a wrong way of thinking of this. If a plugin doesn't need to import something, this is the case for dependency injection, i.e. main app needs to be provide `Multiselect` component to the plugin some way. The way it's done depends on the implementation.

Comment: @EstusFlask thank you for providing hint to me  , this is the case of dependency injection.